# Best way to find if an object exists between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

The following method seems a little naive to me so I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. 2 arrays are involved and they contain objects which I have to compare by a certain property:

```
function exists(objArray, id) {
    var isFound = false;
    objArray.forEach(obj => {
        if (obj.Id == id)
            isFound = true;
    });

    return isFound;
}

var array1, array2;
array1.forEach(obj => exists(array2, obj.Id));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.some` instead.

```
const exists = (objArray, id) => objArray.some(obj => obj.Id === id);
```

(I'd highly recommend using strict equality `===` and not sloppy equality if at all possible)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why force strict equality?

Comment: Because https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465314 It's way too confusing to use sloppy equality

Comment: Using strick equally will check for both the data-type and the value while the other will ignore data-type and only compare value which does not always guarantee correctness.

Comment: Note that while this does short-circuit once it finds a match (a good thing!), in the long run it's still the same performance characteristics as the OP.

Comment: @y2bd performance-wise, is there anything better?

Comment: @MichaelMunta A `for` loop can be faster than `forEach` or anything else - but it's less readable. Performance is almost never an issue to be concerned about. Prioritize clean, readable code first. Only if a section of code proves to be a problem should readability be sacrificed, in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) by passing a comparator function to check if two arrays have a common object.

```js
comparator(obj1, obj2){
  return obj1.id !== obj2.id;
}

let arr1 = [{id: 1}]
let arr2 = [{id: 2}]
_.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, comparator)
```

It returns an empty array if no matching elements, else returns the object with matching id of first array